# Using gtag.js with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: cordova, gtag.js

We've noticed that gtag.js tracking does NOT work if loaded from a local HTML that has been loaded using file:// instead of http://. This was not the case with analytics.js.

Does anyone know how to get gtag.js to work correctly when loaded from a local HTML file? In our case, we're trying to use it in a cordava app. We would rather not use a cordova plug-in if possible.

Comment: This maybe because you have to create a Mobile App account. As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728558/1864395 This may also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977184/1864395

Comment: Hi @jvence - did you get this working?